# What is the difference between `process.env.USER` and `process.env.USERNAME` in Node?

Tags: node.js, windows, bash, environment-variables

This is the most robust documentation I can find for the `process.env` property: https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_env.

It mentions `USER`, but not `USERNAME`. On my machine (Windows/Bash), when I print the contents of `process.env`, I see `USERNAME` (my windows username) but not `USER`. Similarly, `echo $USERNAME` shows my name but `echo $USER` returns nothing.

What is the difference between `USER` and `USERNAME`? Is it an operating system thing? Are they interchangeable?

Comment: I am on OSX and my ENV is `USER`, so it sounds like an OS property

Comment: one is the value of the USER environment variable, the other is the value of the USERNAME environment variable.  In all cases, `process.env.*` returns whatever the set environment variable of the same name is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`process.env` is the process's [environment variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable), which are supplied by the OS to the process.

This object can really contain just about anything, as specified the OS and the process that launches it, but by default Windows stores the username in `USERNAME` and Unix-like systems (Linux, macOS, etc.) store it in `USER`.

Comment: Aha! That explains why this exists: https://www.npmjs.com/package/username. Might use that in my project, or just define my own variable. Thank you, Alexander!

Comment: @KatieFritz: under node >6, you should [use `os.userInfo()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48551852/201952) which gives you the real answer (instead of relying on unreliable env vars)

Comment: Dear @josh3736, When we try to run os.userInfo() in local server i am getting the windows current logged in userid. When the same is moved to linux environment, i am getting the linux loggedin user details. could you please tell me is there any way to the client side username details.( 
1. Has developed Angular App.
2. Calling a GET rest api which was written in node-epxressjs.
3. When we hit from restapi in local, its working fine as the app is in windows.
4. When we try to move project to linux environment, we are getting the linux loggedin user.
This is the scenario.

Answer (score 7):

The documentation about `process.env` that you linked to shows an *example* environment; it is not meant to be normative.  `process.env` can be basically anything -- its values generally have OS defaults provided by the shell, but ultimately they are controlled by the user and/or the process that launched your process.

ie, a user could run

```
$ USER=lies node script.js
```

...and `process.env` would not contain the real username.

---

If you're interested in getting information about the user your process is running as, call [`os.userInfo()`](https://nodejs.org/api/os.html#os_os_userinfo_options), which is (mostly<sup>1</sup>) consistent across platforms.

```
> os.userInfo()
{ uid: -1,
  gid: -1,
  username: 'josh',
  homedir: 'C:\\Users\\josh',
  shell: null }
```

<sup>1 - on Windows, `uid`, `gid`, and `shell` are useless, as seen above</sup>

`os.userInfo()` calls [`uv_os_get_passwd`](http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/misc.html#c.uv_os_get_passwd), which returns the actual current effective user, regardless of what's in environment variables.

> **`uv_os_get_passwd`** Gets a subset of the password file entry for the current effective uid (not the real uid). The populated data includes the username, euid, gid, shell, and home directory. On non-Windows systems, all data comes from [getpwuid_r(3)](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getpwuid_r). On Windows, uid and gid are set to -1 and have no meaning, and shell is *NULL*.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue when trying to connect node.js to mysql via dotenv.

None of the many answers in the web did not resolve my issue.

This worked perfectly well, without the .env file, but only with the information required for authentication inserted into the app.js file. I have tried unsuccessfully any of the posted answers, which include (but not only):

1. changing the information inside the .env file to be with and without ""
2. changing the name of the .env file
3. changing the path of the .env file
4. describing the path to .env file
5. writing different variations of the dotenv commands inside app.js

At last, I have tried to find if I had installed the dotenv using the npm install dotenv command. Also I have tried to show the version of the dotenv from the console.log(dotenv.MY_ENV_VAR); which again, showed undefined.

The issue was related to the fact, that dotenv confused USER (of the system, again like you I was using Linux) with USERNAME (of the mysql database). Actually USER returns the current system user instead of the mysql database user, which I have set to USERNAME in the .env file for convenience. Now it was able to connect to the database!

To check this, you could use:

`console.log(process.env.USER);`

and:

`console.log(process.env.USERNAME);`

1st gives you the system user, whereas the 2nd gives the database user.

Actually, any name for the variable, that holds the username of the mysql database could be used, as far as it does not match the reserved name for the system username in Linux, which is `USER`.