# process.env.USER not what I'm expecting on Linux Mint 18.x

Tags: node.js, linux-mint

I have a simple Node.js test app that uses `dotenv` package.

I have `.env` file

```
USER=DesiredUser
```

**app.js**

```
require('dotenv/config'); 

console.log(process.env.USER);
```

However when I run the app it is using the login user for my computer. 
Any ideas? Doesn't happen on my Windows test.

Answer (score 0):

From [the official docs](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv):

> What happens to environment variables that were already set?
>   We will never modify any environment variables that have already been set. In particular, if there is a variable in your .env file which collides with one that already exists in your environment, then that variable will be skipped.

In this particular case, it's probably a security issue too. On Linux you need `sudo` to become another user.

Answer (score 0):

`dotenv` doesn't override existing environment (as another answer already mentions).

As it can be seen, [it checks if properties exist on `process.env`](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv/blob/v6.0.0/lib/main.js#L63-L67).

As explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48551509/what-is-the-difference-between-process-env-user-and-process-env-username-in), it is `process.env.USERNAME` on Windows and `process.env.USER`, this is the reason why it behaves differently.

If overriding is expected behaviour, it can be achieved at your risk:

```
delete process.env.USER;
require('dotenv/config');
```

Although this won't make the application run as another user.